# Can a electromagnet find a tube underground?

Tags: electromagnetism

I was seeing how an electromagnet could attract a car when it's destroyed, and I was wondering, because I have to find the water tubes in my house (20/40 cm depeer), if I can put a wire inside the tubes and move the magnet until I find the force of the attraction of the two elements.
Unknown evaluation: any electromagnet/wire is good enough?

Expected result: the electromagnet will stick to the wire path.

Comment: Yes, but are you able to find a magnet that is strong enough that you feel the attraction forces at 20-40cm?
If you use an electronic finder anyway - then why not an inductive sensor, then you don't even need the wire - it would sense the water itself.

Comment: @MrGerber that's why I'm asking which kind of elettromagnete would I need

Answer (score 1):

Actually if you can run the wire through the tube there is a simpler method.

Send a radio signal through the wire and use a detector tuned to that signal.

This requires some specialized equipment though.

If the tube was buried recently there may be a tracer wire already next to it you can use for this.